# Call another method immediately before the method call via route in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, url-routing

I'm very new to Symfony framework and I'm trying to replicate what I usually do with other languages (still following the MVC pattern)

The target is to call InitializeSomething() everytime Fly() is called, immediately before.
Here is my code:

```
<?php
// src/Controller/ExampleController.php
namespace App\Controller;

use App\Common\Utils;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

class ExampleController extends BaseController
{
    public function __construct()
    {
      // Initialize vars and so on...
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/example/fly")
     */
    public function Fly()
    {
      // This method is obviously called via the route
    }

    private function InitializeSomething()
    {
      // I would like to call this before Fly() is executed
    }
...
```

of course the easiest way to reach the result is doing this:

```
...
    /**
     * @Route("/example/fly")
     */
    public function Fly()
    {
      $this->InitializeSomething();
      ...
    }
...
```

If there is no other elegant way to do that I will go for that solution, I just would like to avoid to spread all around my code the same method everywhere (the final home for the InitializeSomething method will be in the base class).

Usually with other languages I just call my InitializeSomething inside the constructor, because controller classes are instantiated every time a method is called, but here seems Symfony works in a different way and when constructor is called is too early to make my initialization.

Edit:
Thank you for your advices!
Here are few examples of what I'm going to do.

```
    private function InitializeSomething()
    {
      // Add the connection to a local variable, just to have a shortcut and avoid boilerplate
      $this->dbconnection = $this->getEntityManager()->getConnection();
      $this->dbengine = $this->getDoctrine();

      // Engine start
      if($engine==false) {
        SwitchOnEngine();
      }

      if($engine->rpm < 1000) {
        WaitEngineStart();
      }

      // Other things like logging the event and so on

    }
```

The point is if I forget to initalize the things, something wrong will happen and I want to minimize the errors by letting the machine to intialize the things automatically, once for every class.

Comment: Constructor can work, why do you think it's too early? [Controller event](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/events.html#kernel-controller) is another alternative (but earlier, still). See `controller_arguments` event, too. You can also [call a method](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/calls.html) after instantiation...

Comment: @msg Constructor will not work for controllers since the service locator gets injected using a different method.  On the other hand, a controller event is actually dispatched after the controller is created and provide access to the controller instance.  So if the OP really wants to call their initialization routine then a controller listener is a good choice.  Of course they don't really need to initialize.  Once they gain a bit of experience they will understand why.

Comment: @Cerad There is no indication that he's using `AbstractController`, he might not be using a locator at all, that's why I asked for more details and pointed out different options. But your point is sound.

Comment: What kind of things should `InitializeSomething` actually do? One or two examples would be very helpful. It would also be helpful to name one or two MVC frameworks/projects that apply such a "trick", so that we can do a little focused research on the subject. Anyway, initializations/assignations should happen either in the constructor, or in the controller action (`Fly`) itself.

Comment: @Scare - Based on your initialize example, I would speculate that you are putting too much business logic in your controller.  However, if you really feel you need this functionality then make yourself a controller kernel event listener and call it there.  User msg gave you the link in their first comment.

Answer (score 1):

Symfony has what we call Events. You can check the documentation but this specific event here is called right before the contoller gets executed:
https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/events.html#kernel-controller-arguments

Here you have the full documentation about the Symfony events component so you can understand how to implement what you need:
https://symfony.com/doc/current/event_dispatcher.html

You would end up with something like:

```php
class InitializerListener
{
    public function onKernelController(ControllerEvent $event)
    {
        [$controllerInstance, $actionName] = $this->getController();
        $controllerInstance->initializeSomething();
    }
}
```

And in your config:

```yaml
# config/services.yaml
services:
    App\EventListener\InitializerListener:
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.controller }
```

PS.: If your controller has more than one action method, `getController` returns an array in the format exemplified in the code above. See: https://symfony.com/doc/current/event_dispatcher/before_after_filters.html

Also, don't start your methods with uppercase letters in PHP:
https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/

Comment: Link only answers are frowned upon.  And if you are going to provide a link only answer then at least provide a relevant or useful link.  I think you were trying to direct the OP to kernel events but I'm not sure.  You really should provide an actual answer with a bit of code.

Comment: Not really.  At least in my ever so humble opinion.  You added a better link which is nice but that is the sort of thing usually done with comments.  An answer would include the code for an actual listener and show how to get the controller instance and then call the method in question.

Comment: PS.: I invite you (both) to join the Symfony telegram channel: https://t.me/symfony_en Nicolas Grekas himself is part of it. :-D